# Windows Permissions: Group Ownerships, UAC

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

Problem:
How can I set Windows so that if a user creates a file, his/her primary group has "full read/write/delete" permissions to this file?

**Context**

- Users A and B belong to group QA
- Windows 2008R2
- Machine has UAC (User Access Control)

**Problem Usecase**

- User A creates file X.
- Windows list User A as owner of the file
- User B tries to delete file X.
- Windows gives him "permisison denied"

**Desired Usecase**

- User A creates file X.
- Windows list group QA as owner of the file
- User B tries to delete file X.
- Success

Answer (score 1):

There's no (general, works on all files in all programs) way to do what you are asking.

Instead, give the QA group write/delete permissions on the folder the files are being created in, and ensure things within the folder are set to inherit from above (should be like that by default).